# placing objects like rectangles on a canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I started my app by placing rectangles and other objects on a stackpanel.  That worked will until I wanted to split my rectangles and have two columns of rectangles.  The vertical stackpanel worked well until I needed to split my rectangles into two columns and put stuff on the left and stuff on the right.

So I converted to a canvas.  Now 
mainCanvas.Children.Add(grid); // seems to replace what the last Add placed on screen.  Any ideas how to control the position of items added to the canvas?

Edit:

Ok clearly a canvas is the wrong panel to use.  Two column's of stackpanel's might be made to work.  But when I look at what I am actually trying to accomplish, the column's aren't limited to two, but could be n number of columns.  Why?  Because the application is a flowchart style app that builds a custom language script. The diamond decision shape splits one column into two which can split into two more extra.

I wonder about using a single stack panel and just making a grid with multiple grids horizontally in it.  But mouse events would have to be smart enough to know which grid in the grid your actually in.  Not undoable I think, but not trivial...just looking to see if there is a obvious use this choice that i am missing by being a wpf rookie.

Edit2:
The issue I have with just using a grid is that when the window is stretched a 
grid does not resize to the new window size.

Comment: NEVER use Canvas Layout to anything else than drawing primitives!

Comment: from the very blurry description that you gave to your problem, looks like you need a Grid rather than a canvas. If your layout is nicely structured with columns/rows, you need to use a Grid.

Comment: Canvas is meant for absolute positioning of child elements (without affecting their size). You can set the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` attached properties to place an element  relative to the upper left corner of the Canvas. In code behind this is done by the `Canvas.SetLeft` and `Canvas.SetTop` methods. Anyway, it's unclear if Canvas is an appropriate Panel for your scenario. You need to add some details to your question.

Comment: use a grid with two coloumns and put a vertical stackpanel in each. Then add the rectangles as needed

Comment: Based on your edit, a `UniformGrid` might work for you.  The number of columns can be bound and change dynamically.

Comment: I looked at a uniformgrid and as you add grid children to it, the fill order is horizontal then vertical...1 2 next row, 3 4, next row then expanding to 1 2 3 next row 4 5 6.   I need more control than that.

Answer (score 0):

making a grid of multiple other grids, then using isMouseOver to test to see which grid in the single child of the stackpanel actually needs mouse highlighting works.